# Set Preview to open PDFs in Thumbnail View by default on El Capitan

Tags: preview, macos

I can find nowhere to set Preview to default to Thumbnail View with all PDFs.  I use them every day. I have ticked Thumbnails in the View menu but it does nothing. Does anyone know how to set the default?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting Preview to always open with the sidebar? You can do this in Preview menu > Preferences > PDF tab and selecting the checkbox for "Always show sidebar".

Comment: You can see the screen shot - it does not have that option either?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks SamH.
Have you tried setting Preview to always open with the sidebar? You can do this in Preview menu > Preferences > PDF tab and selecting the checkbox for "Always show sidebar".

I don't have that option:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

Right click, select Get info, select open with, set default